# how can I ignore py~ file in github

Tags: python, git, github

I have already a .gitignore file in my current working directory. But those py~ is still there

Have I done something wrong ?

This is how my .gitignore looks like

```
*.pyc
.idea/workspace.xml
*.log
.idea/dataSources.ids
*~
```

Comment: just don't commit them...

Comment: @heinst thank you for your answer, I have tried to add *.py~ into .gitignore. But in repository those .py~ are still there.

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore

Comment: How'd you solve it @TianchenWu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.gitignore` file add:

```
*.py~
```

If you already have a `*.py~` in your repository, you need remove those from your repository. You can do that via this command (for one file at a time):

```
git rm <file>
```

OR this for all with the extension `*.py~`

```
git rm -r '*.py~'
```

If you need to remove files from your repository, you need to follow these steps

- Commit any pending changes
- Run `git rm --cached <file>`  OR  `git rm -r '*.py~'`
- Commit this change
- Add the line to your `.gitignore`
- Commit a final time